# Stepwise opening of web chat window using DirectLine

Tags: javascript, botframework, bots, chatbot

I have a requirement from client for a better UI/UX experience for users who interact with the chatbot on their website.

The client wants the following:

1. There is a bot icon on the bottom right corner of the website (done)
2. When the user clicks on the bot icon they see the window in the image below. It is basically a smaller web chat window.

[image]

3. After the user type in the chat box the full chat window appears like below:[image]

I am only concerned about the transition from 1 to 2 and 3. I have pretty much designed the bot UI and I can transition from part 1 to 3 directly. I cannot figure out how to do 2. How to have a smaller window roll up to a full size chat window.

I am looking into webchat framework and have pretty much completed the color, font and UI changes as you see in the second image. I need help two things:

1. Is it a good idea to have a transition like I explained above.
2. Directions on how to do it. I haven't found anything yet that can help me do this. Pointing me in the correct direction would be helpful!

Comment: I am using DirectLine webchat embedded in a .NET website. Upon further reading it looks like React bundle gives me more options to customize UI/UX. But my website is not in React so this won't work.

Comment: Which customization options from the React bundle would you want to use? Just for clarity, the React flavor of Web Chat (`window.ReactDOM.render()`) does not require the website you are embedding Web Chat into to be built in React. All it requires is simple HTML. To that end, I'm not familiar of any Web Chat functionality that can be done in the React flavor that can't be done in the non-React flavor (`window.WebChat.renderWebChat()`).

Comment: your last comment is what i was thinking too. Although I am trying to convince the client that from a UX point of view this is not a good idea. I would rather have them open the web chat to make use of adaptive welcome card and the interactive buttons on it rather than jumping straight ahead into chatting with the bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consideration implementing a modal, or similar, on your page that mimics the minimized Web Chat button. Upon selecting, the modal opens displaying #2. Because it's a modal built out of your website, you can control the styling allowing you to format it how you need, including adding a "Type message here" input field. When a user enters a message and submits (hits enter), this would open/begin the Web Chat session with the initial message from the user being forwarded to Web Chat once connected.

Hope of help!